# Postgres Replication - WAL sender throw connection reset by peer

Tags: postgresql, linux, pgpool

Good morning everyone,

I hope containment is going well for you.
For my part, I use this time to set up a Postgres 11 cluster on my servers, but I have some problems. Can you help me?

I've got this error coming in a loop on the postres master.

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2020-05-06 08:40:21.379 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2020-05-06 08:40:21.379 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2020-05-06 08:40:21.380 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-05-06 08:40:21.390 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-05-06 08:40:19 UTC
2020-05-06 08:40:21.390 UTC [21] LOG:  entering standby mode
2020-05-06 08:40:21.391 UTC [21] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/165A760
2020-05-06 08:40:21.391 UTC [21] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/165A760: wanted 24, got 0
2020-05-06 08:40:21.391 UTC [21] LOG:  trigger file found: /var/lib/postgresql/data/promote_to_master.tmp
2020-05-06 08:40:21.391 UTC [21] LOG:  redo is not required
2020-05-06 08:40:21.392 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2020-05-06 08:40:21.394 UTC [21] LOG:  selected new timeline ID: 2
2020-05-06 08:40:21.416 UTC [21] LOG:  archive recovery complete
2020-05-06 08:40:21.421 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-05-06 08:40:29.133 UTC [31] ERROR:  cannot execute SQL commands in WAL sender for physical replication
2020-05-06 08:40:29.134 UTC [31] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2020-05-06 08:40:34.275 UTC [32] ERROR:  cannot execute SQL commands in WAL sender for physical replication
2020-05-06 08:40:34.275 UTC [32] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2020-05-06 08:40:53.105 UTC [33] ERROR:  cannot execute SQL commands in WAL sender for physical replication
2020-05-06 08:40:53.106 UTC [33] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2020-05-06 08:41:24.186 UTC [34] ERROR:  cannot execute SQL commands in WAL sender for physical replication
2020-05-06 08:41:24.186 UTC [34] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2020-05-06 08:42:19.287 UTC [35] ERROR:  cannot execute SQL commands in WAL sender for physical replication
2020-05-06 08:42:19.287 UTC [35] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2020-05-06 08:43:49.475 UTC [36] ERROR:  cannot execute SQL commands in WAL sender for physical replication
2020-05-06 08:43:49.475 UTC [36] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

The client postgres display this one during pg_basebackup :

```
pg_basebackup: could not send replication command "SHOW data_directory_mode": FATAL:  Backend throw an error message
DETAIL:  Exiting current session because of an error from backend
HINT:  BACKEND Error: "cannot execute SQL commands in WAL sender for physical replication"
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

My cluster is set like this:

```
postgres-0 -> 192.168.9.227
postgres-1 -> 192.168.187.162
```

Virtual IP for the Master :

```
db -> 10.105.49.122
```

I use a pgpool instance on each postgres host that listens on port 5433 and is connected to a backend on port 5432.

My configuration is done with these commands:

```
su postgres -c initdb
host_ip=$(getent ahostsv4 $HOSTNAME | cut -d ' ' -f1 | head -n 1)
echo "host    replication     ${REPLICA_USER}     ${host_ip}/32  md5" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
REPLICATE_FROM="$(getent ahostsv4 "${MASTER_HOSTNAME}" | cut -d ' ' -f1 | head -n 1)"
echo "${postgres_conf}" | envsubst >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
echo "${recovery_conf}" | envsubst > /var/lib/postgresql/data/recovery.conf

su postgres -c postgres &
echo "CREATE USER ${REPLICA_USER} WITH REPLICATION LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '${REPLICA_PASSWORD}';" | psql -U postgres
```

The variable $postgres_conf is equal to :

```
listen_addresses = '*'
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 8
hot_standby = on
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cp /var/lib/postgresql/data/%p /var/lib/postgresql/data/archive/%f'
```

The variable $recovery_conf is equal to :

```
standby_mode = on
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
primary_conninfo = 'host=${REPLICATE_FROM} port=5432 user=${REPLICA_USER} password=${REPLICA_PASSWORD}'
trigger_file = '/var/lib/postgresql/data/promote_to_master.tmp'
```

On the Master I do:

```
touch /var/lib/postgresql/data/promote_to_master.tmp
```

And on the Slave I go:

```
PGPASSWORD=${REPLICA_PASSWORD} su postgres -c "pg_basebackup -h ${REPLICATE_FROM} -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -U ${REPLICA_USER} -v -P"
```

Did anyone has the solution ?

Comment: What version of `pg_basebackup` are you running?  What version database server are you trying to connect to?

Comment: I use postgres 11 : 
/ # postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.7
/ # pg_basebackup --version
pg_basebackup (PostgreSQL) 11.7

Comment: I think my problem come from pgpool that didn't forward correctly my connexion.